# How to group by on a column from a sub query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have  a tasks table with

```
tasks_id | start_time_id | end_time_id | start_date | end_date

t1       | st_1          | et_1        | 20180903   | 20180903
t2       | st_2          | et_2        | 20180903   | 20180903
t3       | st_3          | et_3        | 20180903   | 20180903
t4       | st_4          | et_4        | 20180903   | 20180903
t5       | st_5          | et_5        | 20180903   | 20180903
t6       | st_6          | et_6        | 20180903   | 20180904
```

`start_time` and `end_time` are ids that join with `time_table` to get the military hours like

```
   time_id   | military_hour 
   st1       | 0
   st2       | 2
   st3       | 7
   st4       | 16
   st5       | 18
   st6       | 23
   et1       | 0
   et2       | 2
   et3       | 8
   et4       | 16
   et5       | 18
   et6       | 0
```

I can join with `tasks` table with `time_table` **twice** if I want to know the military hours of both `start_time_id` and `end_time_id`.

```
SELECT        t1.tasks_id as task_inst_id,
              t1.start_time_id,
              t1.end_time_id,
              t1.end_date as end_date,
              t1.start_date as start_date
      FROM task_instances t1
      INNER JOIN time_table td1 
              ON t1.start_time_id = td1.time_id
      INNER JOIN time_table td2 
              ON t1.end_time_id = td2.time_id
```

**I can divide the military hours in windows of 4 hours each so in a day there are 6 windows or military hour groups** like

```
  (FLOOR(military_hour / 4)) AS military_hour_group
```

I want to know `no of all the tasks that either started or ended in those windows if I pass a particular day`.

I tried

```
SELECT
tq1.start_military_hour_group,
tq1.end_date,
COUNT(tq1.task_inst_id) as no_of_tasks
FROM
(
SELECT        t1.tasks_id as task_inst_id,
              t1.start_time_id,
              t1.end_time_id,
              t1.end_date as end_date,
              (FLOOR(td1.military_hour / 4)*4) AS start_military_hour_group,
              (FLOOR(td2.military_hour / 4)*4) AS end_military_hour_group
      FROM task_instances t1
      INNER JOIN time_table td1 
              ON t1.start_time_id = td1.time_id
      INNER JOIN time_table td2 
              ON t1.end_time_id = td2.time_id 

      /* I don't know how to put the where condition */

      WHERE t1.end_date = '20180903':: int 
)tq1
GROUP BY tq1.start_military_hour_group,tq1.end_date
ORDER BY tq1.end_date,tq1.start_military_hour_group;
```

I know I am missing something but what exactly?

**I am joining twice so I guess it creates 2 rows for the same row from tasks table also should I take end_date or start_date?**

Please explain.

E.g. For the sample set

```
0 - 3 group - 2 tasks
4-7 group - 1 task
8-11 group - 0 
12-15 group - 0
16 - 19 group - 2 taks
20-23 group - 1 task
```

Comment: what is the expected output for your data?

Comment: @RadimBača I have just updated. Please see.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It says 24 hour format 0 -23. And then I group them up in a group of 4 hours each using `(FLOOR(military_hour / 4)) AS military_hour_group`. It's stored in `time_table`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know. It's just the name table schema uses.

Comment: You could use `WIDTH_BUCKET(expression, min, max, buckets)` like `WIDTH_BUCKET(military_hour, 0, 24, 6) AS buckets` that gives you the number of the bucket in which `military_hour` falls. Than group by `buckets`.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `'20180903':: int ` can be simplified to `20180903`. Also in the sample data the tasks all start and end at the same hour. (because e.g. for `tasks_id = t1` start hour `st_1` is `0` and end hour `et_1` is also `0`.  Is that intended?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. But 0 simply means task starts and ends in the same hour

Comment: Few things - your time_table is very strange approche? What for? You have simple hours from 0 to 23 you can divide work with it without any problem. Whant 4 hrs gap or other gaps it is very simple. Also you table has strange values some are equal to ech other as st_1 and et_1 some are diffrent as st_3 and et_3. 
Then wwhy you ask us what should you use start date or end date. You should know what you want - do you want to group by hour os starting job or ending job. If both then don;t be surprise that you have  task that start in one group and end in other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first. You should rethink your data model - start_time_id and end_time_id and a separate table with redundant data(time_table) is not a good design. You can have hours as start_time and end_time.

Now, lets resolve your problem on your actual design.

```
with time_groups as (select * from (values (0, '0 - 3 group'),
                                           (1, '4 - 7 group'),
                                           (2, '8 - 11 group'),
                                           (3, '12 - 15 group'),
                                           (4, '16 - 19 group'),
                                           (5, '20 - 23 group')) a (id, name))

select tg.name, coalesce(tasks,0) tasks
  from (select tt1.military_hour/4 time_group_id, count(*)  tasks
          from task_instances ti
          LEFT join time_table tt1 on ti.start_time_id=tt1.time_id
          LEFT JOIN time_table tt2 on ti.end_time_id=tt2.time_id
         where ti.end_date='20180903' or ti.end_date is null
         group by tt1.military_hour/4
         order by 1) a
  right join time_groups tg on a.time_group_id=tg.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about it another way. This code is simpler, albeit likely less efficient than joining twice.

```
select  count(distinct ti.tasks_id), floor(td.military_hour/4)*4 time_group
from time_dimension td
join time_instance ti on td.time_id in (ti.start_time_id, ti.end_time_id)
group by  floor(td.military_hour/4)*4 time_group
where td.end_date = '2018090'
```

Comment: It does not give me the total number of tasks though :( . I gives me a count of time_ids

Comment: then change the count to count(distinct ti.tasks_id)

Comment: but ,maybe that's inaccurate.. let me think about that a sec